# How to get absolute positions of touches and layer objects?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm having a weird issue with cocos2d-x when trying to detect which character (currently a CCLayer-extending object) I'm touching. The problem is that the location of the sprite I'm clicking on never matches the touch location that is registered.

I've tried different conversion functions but neither of them seem to work.

Any idea about how can I detect in ccTouchesBegan where a map (CCLayer) is being touched in the same 'scale' than the characters (also CCLayer's)? How can I get the absolute position in the map of the touch poisition as I receive it (I will move the character to the clicked position)?

I know that they may be very basic questions, but I've been looking for the answer for some hours and I can't find the solution. Any suggestion either for cocos2d-x or cocos2d is really welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) In order to detect whether world point is in the node, I use following function:

```
    
    bool VUtils::isNodeAtPoint(cocos2d::CCNode* node, cocos2d::CCPoint& touchLocation) {                
        CCPoint nodePoint = node->convertToNodeSpace(touchLocation);
        CCRect rect = CCRectMake(0, 0, node->getContentSize().width, node->getContentSize().height);
        return rect.containsPoint(nodePoint);
    }
```

2) touchLocation - is point in world coordinates, in order to get it use CCTouch::getLocation() method in your touch listeners.

Comment: 2) CCTouch::getLocation() gives me the position of the click relative to the low left corner of the view screen, not of the whole map (world).

The problem is that I don't get both touch and node location in the same coordinates scheme (world, screen, whatever...).

Comment: "the view screen", what do you mean?

CCTouch::getLocation() - returns world coordinate, isNodeAtPoint - converts this coordinate to coordinate system of the target node.